# tooltip not working in chart

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

```
require([
    "dojox/charting/Chart",
    "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip", 
    "dojox/charting/themes/Tom",
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",
    "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function (Chart, Tooltip, theme, LinesPlot) {
    var chartData = [4.92, 4.98, 4.89];
    var chart = new Chart("chartNode");
    var tip = new Tooltip(chart, "default");

    chart.setTheme(theme);

    chart.addPlot("default", {
        type: LinesPlot,
        markers: true
    });

    chart.addAxis("x");
    chart.addAxis("y", {
        min: 4.90,
        max: 5.0000,
        vertical: true
    });

    chart.addSeries("Monthly Sales", chartData);

    chart.render();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jxJZ6/1/)

This chart works fine, except with the tooltip option activated. However i can't find the reason of that. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the Tooltip before you even add the plot "default". If you move your tooltip declaration after adding the plot "default", then it should work fine. Here is your example with the tooltip rearranged.

```
chart.addPlot("default", {
    type: LinesPlot,
    markers: true
});
var tip = new Tooltip(chart, "default");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jxJZ6/2/